# Hypergeometric probability function choose 2 balls

Tags: probability, statistics

> Two balls are drawn at random from a box containing ten balls numbered 0, 1, ..., 9. Let the
>   random variable X be the maximum of the two numbers drawn. **Find** the 
>   probability function $f(x)$.

This is **hypergeometric** isn't it?

So we have $N = 10, n = 2$, and the success size will be $r = x + 1$, since we can only choose from $\{0, 1, \ldots, x\}$

How do I write it in the form?

Comment: Hypergeometric would be useful if you wanted to know the probability of getting only balls numbered 3 or lower: ${4\choose 2}{6 \choose 0}/{10 \choose 2},$ but that is _not exactly_ what you want to know for $p(x).$ That would be $P(max \le 3).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is hypergeometric isn't it?

Somewhat similar, but no.   What you seek is the probability for selecting one of the two balls being exactly $x$ *and* the other from the numbers in $\{0,..,x-1\}$, when you are selecting any two balls from those in the set $\{0, .., 9\}$, without bias but no repetition.

> $$\mathsf P(\max\{X_1,X_2\}=x) ~=~\dfrac{\dbinom 1 1\dbinom {?}{1}}{\dbinom {?}2}\mathbf 1_{x\in\{1,..,9\}}$$

Comment: Is the numerator question mark $x $? And the denominator $x+1$ as well?

Comment: The numerator is, the denominator is not.

Comment: So the numerator is $x$, but the denominator is not $x+1$?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start. If you are drawing 2 balls without replacement
from among 10, then there are ${10 \choose 2} = 45$ possible 
unordered outcomes. The
maximum number $X$ can take values 1 through 9.

$P(X = 1) = 1/45,$ because the only possible pair with that maximum is 0 and 1.

$P(X = 2) = 2/45,$ because 02 or 12 will do.

Keep going ...

$P(X = 9) = 9/45,$ because why?